# 2 identical ListViews with small differences inside delegate

Tags: delegates, qml, qtdeclarative

I've got two almost identical qml files. I list one of them here, the differences of the other one shown with the comment lines:

```
// MessageView.qml; diff. to ThreadView.qml is shown with comment lines
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property var model
    property var selectedThread: threadsList.currentItem.myThread
    property alias spacing: threadsList.spacing
    signal activated(var selectedThread)
    id: root

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        id: threadsList
        model: root.model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            property var myThread: message // the other file contains `thread` instead of `message` here

            color: threadsList.currentItem == this ? "cyan"
                                                     : index % 2 ? "lightblue" : "lightsteelblue"
            width: parent.width
            height: ti.implicitHeight

            MessageItem { // the other file contains `ThreadItem` instead of `MessageItem` here
                id: ti
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.margins: 8
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    threadsList.currentIndex = index
                    activated(root.selectedThread)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These 2 components are intended to be similar-looking list views with minor differences in delegate appearance. How do I merge these two files into one to be able to use them like this?

```
MerdedView { 
    MessageItem {
        // more property customization
    }
}
MerdedView { 
    ThreadItem {
        // more property customization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only small differences inside delegate, so you need to extract the common codes. For example, `MerdedViewDelegate.qml`:

```
Rectangle {
    id: viewItem

    property var myThread
    //other properties: color, width, height, ...

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            //use the attached property in ListView
            viewItem.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the `MergedView.qml` just like your `MessageView.qml`, except the delegate is now changed to an alias property:

```
//MergedView.qml
Item {
    property alias delegate: threadsList.delegate
    //other properties

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        id: threadsList
        model: root.model 
    }
}
```

Finally, you can write your QML like this:

```
MergedView {
    delegate: MergedViewDelegate{ 
        myThread: message    //or something similar
        MessageItem { /* ... */ }
    }
}

MergedView {
    delegate: MergedViewDelegate{ 
        myThread: thread
        ThreadItem { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also used Loader to get rid of a separate MergedViewDelegate